# Output not displayed i shiny app using shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a `sliderInput` in a `menuItem` which can be moved and the selected number needs to be displayed on the screen. Below is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)    

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
            sidebarMenu(
                # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"),
                         sliderInput("slider", "Slider Input", min = 0, max = 10, step = 1, value = 5))
                )
            )


body <- dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem("dashboard", textOutput("Dashboard"))
            )
    )


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar,
    body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$Dashboard <- renderText({
        paste("You've selected:", input$slider)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Ideally, I should see the number selected but that does not happen, unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem when there is an input inside a `menuItem`. You can do:

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id="tabs",
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")), 
    conditionalPanel(
      "input.tabs == 'dashboard'",
      sliderInput("slider", "Slider Input", 
                  min = 0, max = 10, step = 1, value = 5))
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane. The code works but when I add multiple Inputs it fails. Will check the link you shared and try out the solution their too!

Comment: After following instructions at: (github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/167), I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which works.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"),
               sliderInput("slider", "Slider Input", min = 0, max = 10, step = 1, value = 5))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    textOutput("dashboard")

  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dashboard <- renderText({
    paste("You've selected:", input$slider)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Works well with a single `tabItem` but when I add multiple tabItems the results do not show in the body. My final app has a number of tabs with tables and graphs.